# Переход к "ответам" на сообщение

Tags: php, java, вконтакте, telegram, social-network

Хотелось бы узнать как можно реализовать "переход к ответам", который реализован в соц. сетях (в частности в Телеграмме и в ВКонтакте).

Есть мысли по поводу передачи id сообщения сайту и подгрузки "ближайших" сообщений из БД, но так ли это разумно? И если мое сообщение видно пользователю, то есть в момент переписки оно отображается на экране, желательно сделать так чтобы скрипт подсвечивал сообщение без обращения к БД (если так возможно).

Хотелось бы узнать как лучше реализовать данный алгоритм и, если у кого-либо есть примеры решения на любом из языков, то буду благодарен, если поделитесь ресурсом или самим кодом.

Comment: Попробуйте подробнее описать фичу. Пока что не очень понятно какое именно поведение и в каком случае вам нужно

Comment: У меня есть чат, в нем реализована функция в которой я могу "ответить" пользователю. То есть она содержит мой ответ на чужой текст (и то и то присутствует на экране). В выводимом элементе показывает мой текст и "ответ" (сообщение на которое я ответил). Нужно сделать так чтобы по нажатию на "ответ" программа автоматически показывала/подсвечивала нужный элемент. Если элемент находится на экране (то есть виден пользователю), то скроллит к нему и посдвечивает. Если его нет на экране, то нужно из БД загрузить его и ближайшие 10 снизу и сверху сообщений. Надеюсь правильно все объяснил)

Comment: Да, так понятнее стало) Теперь, наверное, вам надо рассказать как в данный момент реализовано отображение сообщений. Ибо можно по разному, например фронт может быть отдельным от бэка и тогда, если в локальных данных на фронте сообщения, на которое отвечают нет, то надо запрос на бэк делать с передачей ID и обрабатывать ответ. Если всё на бэке происходит, то тут хз - сам такое не делал) Однако принцип должен быть примерно одинаковый. Передача ID и подгрузка из БД. Сложность тут, по моему, в наличии большого кол-ва неотображаемых сообщений между отображаемыми сейчас и изначальным сообщением.

Comment: Я уже справился с вариантом где "ответ" виден на экране. Теперь автоматически скроллит и подсвечивает нужный мне ответ. Если знаете, то как лучше реализовать подгрузку с БД, а если точнее, как оптимизировать запрос ?

Допустим у меня id сообщения 809, то есть мне нужны сообщения с 800 до 819. Как лучше передать запрос в SQL чтобы выдало "диапазон" данных, если так можно сказать ? Спасибо.)

Comment: Тут немного зависит от реализации схемы БД. Немного подумав, я не придумал как это за один запрос сделать, но можно за 2. Или даже за один, в самом запросе объединив результаты 2 запросв. Запросы должны быть примерно такими: `select from messages where chat_id=1 and id<? order by id ASC limit 10` и `select from messages where chat_id=1 and id<? order by id DESC limit 10`. Сами запросы, вроде, можно через `union` соединить примерно так: `select ... union select ...`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я еще смотрел вариант с BETWEEN, думаю что можно объединить оба варианта и будет то что мне требуется. Благодарю !)